# Adding subtotals using GROUPING SETS

Tags: postgresql, group-by

For a data table I would like to create the following table:

| store | department | gender | workers_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Light | Male | 10 |
| A | Light | Female | 5 |
| A | Plumbing | Male | 20 |
| A | Plumbing | Female | 0 |
|  | 2 |  | 35 |
| B | Food | Male | 12 |
| B | Food | Female | 12 |
|  | 1 |  | 24 |

For each store department and gender, I would like to count the number of workers and for each store to count the number of departments and workers

Comment: Have you got sample data

Answer (score 1):

This is a translation of your description into SQL:

```
... GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((store, department, gender), (store))
```